# Count distinct pairs of strings that contain at least one common character at the same position

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a more efficient way to count distinct pairs of strings in an array that have at least one common character at the same position. The strings will always have the same length of 3. For example,

- "**a**bc", **a**cb": counts
- "b**un**", "f**un**": counts
- "xyz", "yzx": doesn't count
- "one", "two": doesn't count

I've tried writing a function that checks if they match and then count them using for loops, but it doesn't seem to be so efficient, especially when the array is huge.

```cpp
bool match(std::string a, std::string b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a.at(i) == b.at(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    const int count = 100000;
    std::string strings[count] = {...};

    long long int matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            if (match(strings[i], strings[j])) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: if with "efficient" you mean algorithm complexity, no, if you mean "program can run faster"  yes, and if so, let me know and i will answer with what i think you can do

Comment: @Berto99 Yes, I meant is there any way that the program can be run faster.

Comment: 3 for string match is very magical and will fail if strings are not 3 in length.  That should either be a string length check, or a constant if it must be 3 forever.

Comment: BTW, xor will return 0 if 2 letters are the same and can be used for "word" size or even SIMD register size checks to make things go faster.  Just need to be careful of string lengths so you don't read past end of string or `\0` char.  Just need to scan your word for an 8-bit 0 value after a compare.  That can be done in a binary search manner at least and maybe faster.

Comment: (Note - since strings are always 3 bytes, the best you can do is a 4-byte read including the 0 char which means it may not help much for these sizes...)

Comment: "if with "efficient" you mean algorithm complexity, no" - Do you have proof that quadratic is the best possible complexity for this problem? There's a linear time solution if the alphabet size is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the list (assuming the strings has 3 chars):

1. is actual the only one that might not be already done by your compiler: pass the `std::string` by `const&`, so that you don't need to copy them every time you call the function

```
bool match(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){...}
```

2. avoid useless branches in your code (can be optimized already by some branch prediction algorithm):

```
 // from 
if (match(strings[i], strings[j])) {
   matches++;
}
 // to
matches = matches + match(strings[i], strings[j];
```

3. loop unrolling (which can been done already by your compiler):

```
bool match(std::string a, std::string b) {
    return a.at(0) == b.at(0) || a.at(1) == b.at(1) || a.at(2) == b.at(2);
}
```

4. You can also try to parallelize those conditions (depends on architecture, can be done already by the compiler) using `|` and so all the conditions can be done in parallel by ALU, instead using `|` must be performed step by step (short circuit evaluation):

```
bool match(std::string a, std::string b) {
    return a.at(0) == b.at(0) | a.at(1) == b.at(1) | a.at(2) == b.at(2);
}
```

5. Compile using the highest optimization (can increase the compilation time), using `-O3`
6. use pre-increment instead of post-increment (post increment will generate a second variable to return every time you use it, pre-increment no):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; ++j) {
    }
}
```

7. by this line `std::string strings[count] = {...};` I suppose you are using initializarer list, and so the computation can actually be performed at compile time if you use `std::string_view` and so at runtime there is no compilation to perform (this works only if the strings are known at compile time)
8. decrease cache misses, but this depends 100% on architecture
9. inline the function (so that your program don't have to do a jump every time to call `match`):

```
// from:
bool match(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){...}
//to:
inline bool match(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){...}
```

10. use `operator[]` instead of `.at()` because it does not make any kind of bounds checking

```
bool match(std::string a, std::string b) {
    return a[0] == b[0] | a[1] == b[1] | a[2] == b[2];
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure everything you list here a compiler "should" do automatically.  Without profiling it's hard to say where the slowest part is, but I would guess it is the reading from memory of the chars.  Being able to read that memory all at once might be the one thing that compiler cannot "legally" do without help.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yes absolutely, infact in the first point i've said that that could be the only point that might not been done by compiler

Comment: Since you're optimizing, why `at()` over `operator[]`? `at()` has explicit bounds checking.

Comment: @user975989 oh yes, you are right, i'll add it immediatly

Comment: Also your match is incorrect, it should be `||` or `|`.

Comment: @user975989 yes yes, I had just seen it